# Cost associated with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-tables

What is the cost associated with Azure Cosmos DB? Does the bill depend upon the database or containers we create? Also, does the bill depend on when we read/write data to containers or starts billing from the time we create Azure Cosmos DB? If that's the case, is there an option to disable/pause Azure Cosmos DB Account in Azure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pricing for Cosmos DB is described pretty nicely here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-pricing-works. To summarize, you are charged for the capacity you reserved as well as for storage.

To answer your specific questions:

> Does the bill depend upon the database or containers we create?

Yes. The moment you create a database or a container with throughput, that capacity is reserved for you so you start paying for that whether or not you use it. Please note that you can create a database without throughput and in that case you're not charged.

> Also, does the bill depend on when we read/write data to containers or
>   starts billing from the time we create Azure Cosmos DB?

Account creation is free. The billing starts when you create a database or a container in that account with throughput.

> If that's the case, is there an option to disable/pause Azure Cosmos
>   DB Account in Azure?

Unfortunately no. You will need to delete the resources to stop the billing.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to update database settings to remove throughput mentioned before?

Comment: `Is it possible to update database settings to remove throughput mentioned before?` - Unfortunately the answer is no. You could reduce the throughput to a minimum of 400 but cannot make it 0 or delete throughput.

Comment: If I create a database 'Autoscale 4000 RU/s' what will be the monthly price?